# PHP 5.5 - using yield with PDO transactions, is it possible?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, yield

I want to make use of generators to handle over chunks of data from a database query while using the minimum ammount of memory at the same time (one of the advantage for generators).

The problem I've found while using generators is associated with this piece of code:

```
if (!empty($this->attributes["queries"])) {
    if (!empty($query)) {
        if (!empty($this->attributes["queries"][$query])) {
            $this->attributes["queries"][$query]->output();
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($this->attributes["queries"] as $query) {
            $query->output();
        }
    }
}
```

Optimizations aside, what this code does is:

1. Checks if we have any allocated SQL query
2. Checks if a specific SQL query was given to execute (ignore any other)
3. In case a specific SQL query was given and it exists, execute it with `output()`
4. If no specific SQL query was given, traverse all SQL queries and execute them with `output()`

The problem is this works flawlessly for any kind of SQL query EXCEPT the most used one: `SELECT`.

The problem lies within this piece of code:

```
if (!empty($query)) {
    if (!empty($this->attributes["queries"][$query])) {
        if ($this->attributes["queries"][$query]->attributes["type"] === "SELECT") {
            if ($output = $this->attributes["link"]->prepare($this->attributes["queries"][$query]->attributes["query"], [\PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => \PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY])) {
                if ($output->execute(!empty($this->attributes["queries"][$query]->attributes["parameters"]) ? $this->attributes["queries"][$query]->attributes["parameters"] : null)) {
                    while ($row = $output->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        yield $row;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method (called `input` to differentiate it from the `output` method with executes any other function) follows the same logic.

- Checks if the specified SQL query exists
- Prepares the SQL query specified as a query/parameters pair
- Execute the SQL query and `yield` the results

I'm a bit lost here so I would like some light on this subject. Seems like yielding any data row makes any other execution branch unusable (I can perform as many `SELECT` queries as I want, but no transactional operation works (`CREATE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc. just isn't issued or executed but not commited).

Can you give me (or help me design) a piece of pseudo code to reflect the correct pattern for this? Even if I code with PHP 5.5 a lot there's still things I don't know or haven't experienced, so a bit of help would be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT:** what I mean with the `input()` and `output()` methods is my scheme currently works but **ONLY** if I separate the `SELECT` query into its own `input()` method (so using the generator doesn't break the other SQL queries) and leave the `output()` method for any other SQL operation.

Comment: As I told you before, the whole idea is flawed. No yield or any other trick will make it usable.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Let's try to gather 2000 rows from a table representing some invoices, or a list of items or a list of orders. With the 'usual' way of retrieving records, you must implement the query logic in-place. Even if we're talking about doing things 'correctly' and using the MVC model, I would like for a single method to carry all the database access logic and allow me to code in a cleaner and easier fashion. Plus I always like to think about my methods not being accesed by me, but hundreds of potential users, hence the need for a procedure like this :P

Comment: Everything you are talking about is possible without such an awkward monster. All the hundreds of potential users who **already** know SQL and have not a slightest idea of your local inventions. Yet I am kinda jealous to your imagination.

Comment: I maybe don't understand what you want to do here, but it is easy to fetch rows as they were in an array. You can do it with Iterators for example... Generators are not so different from Iterators if you use them in a foreach loop...

Comment: My problem was about having a single function handling two execution paths: one where I could feed each result with the `yield` keyword, and the other for non-yielding operations (for example, dropping a database table, which is a one-way operation). The problem is I took the use of the `yield` keyword the wrong way. When you use the `yield` keyword within a function, there can't be a `return` statement, as it invalidates the purpose of a generator (which makes the function call itself back until the generator has ended providing values). Separating the core logic solved my problem :)